# dcolumn with alignment to comma

Tags: dcolumn

this is supposed to be an easy question, but I didn't find a clear answer anywhere.

I want to use `dcolumn` with comma as a separator. However, I found different solutions and the manual is unclear to me. It says in `D{>sep.tex<}{>sep.dvi<}{>decimal places<}`, I have to choose ',' instead of '.' to achieve alignment to the comma. However I dont understand the difference between `{>sep.tex<}` and `{>sep.dvi<}`.

Also I found a solution where someone only used `{>sep.dvi<}` as a comma, whereas the manual suggests to use comma in both, `{>sep.tex<}` and `{>sep.dvi<}`.

Can someone explain the difference and tell me how to specify it correctly?

MWE simple as that:
`\newcolumntype{G}{D..{2.1}}` - where `G` currently aligns to the decimal point, not the comma, in case of 2 decimal places before the separator and 1 after.

Thanks.

Comment: `\newcolumntype{G}{D{,}{,}{2.1}}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke I know this is what the manual suggests and it works, I have tested it. But what is the difference between the two arguments? In another thread I found sthg like `\newcolumntype{G}[1]{D{.}{,}{2.1}}`.

Comment: The `{>sep.tex<}` is the one to match in the tex code and the `{>sep.dvi<}` is the one, which will appear in the document.

Comment: @HenriMenke Ahh from your wording I think I got it. So `{>sep.tex<}` does the actual alignment, whereas `{>sep.dvi<}` is the visible outcome. If you want to make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Remarks

Let's look at the definition `\newcolumntype{>name<}{D{>sep.tex<}{>sep.dvi<}{>decimal places<}}`:

1. `>name<` is the name for your new column, limited to one character.
2. `>sep.tex<` is the character, which is used for alignment in the TeX code.
3. `>sep.dvi<` is the character, which will substitute the `>sep.tex<`-character in the output (in most cases identical to `>sep.tex<`, because we only use alignment).
4. `>decimal places<` is either `-1` for auto detect or `pre comma places.post comma places`.

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}% for \Smiley
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{G}{D{,}{\Smiley}{2.1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|G|G|}
    10,2 & 5,3 \\
    8,1 & 10,2 \\
    4,4 & 8,1 \\
    8.1 & 10.22 \\ % <-- broken by purpose
    3,4 & 8,5 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: What if I want to put a text in one of the rows and keep it centralized?